# Control Targeted Browser Window

Tags: windows, google-chrome, internet, windows-explorer

When I have multiple browser windows open, I don't know how to control which is chosen to open a new link - when that link is selected in a non-browser application.

For example, when I click a web link in OneNote or Word, the already-open browser that is chosen is whichever one of my Internet Explorer windows happens to have the least number of open browsing tabs.

I would like to change that behavior.  I'd like that each newly opened page, as selected from a non-browser app, always goes to the last internet explorer window I had active.

Can this be done?

Comment: what version of office and iexplorer? os?